# Explain this-> NSLog(@"testString: %@", testString);

Tags: objective-c

```
NSLog(@"testString: %@", testString);
```

P.S. the second testString is a pointer to a NSString.

I found the above in a tutorial, and it says (%@ means an Objective-C object).

So, what does the first @ do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@"" just means a string declaration in objective-c.

e.g.

```
 [myObject setString:@"my string"];
```

or

```
 NSString *myString = [NSString stringWithString:@"the second String"];
 [myObject setString:myString];
```

So in NSLog you are saying..

NSLog .. this string @"   text   " .. the %@ pointer links to things outside the string after the commar.

E.g.

```
 NSLog(@"String 1 : %@ , String 2 : %@", string1, string2);
```

Answer (score 0):

`@""` is a constant string defined at compile time.

Answer (score 0):

Since Objective-C is a superset of C, it needs to keep the compatibility with all the feature of the C language.

The `@` in the front only means to want to make a `NSString` object. So `"test"` makes a C-string, and `@"test"` makes a `NSString` object.

Note that you can change the type returned by the construction `@""` in the compiler settings (if don't want to use `NSString`).

Answer (score 0):

the first at sign is for string literals. Every time(i have ever seen) you use a string in your code you use the form @"mystring", and it is processed at compile time.  This `@""` is necessary to differentiate c-strings from Objective-C NSStrings.  It is also immutable.

Also,
The `%@` is a string format specifier, this one in particular is for... strings. If you want to see some other string format specifiers please [see their documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html).